# Storyboard : Pop to root view controller from subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

this is my first app so this should be simple for experienced ios developer. I have a story board with navigation controller and in one of my view controller there is a subview. On click in subview, I want to return to the root controller but unfortunately it is not working. 
Subview Controller

```
- (IBAction)doneAction:(id)sender {
    if ([self.parentViewController isKindOfClass:[PlayViewController class]]){
        PlayViewController *pControl = (PlayViewController *) self.parentViewController;
        [pControl goToMainView];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"NOT AN INSTANCE");
    }
}
```

View Controller

```
-(void)goToMainView{
    NSLog(@"I AM HERE");
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    /*SWRevealViewController *secondViewController =
    [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"gameController"];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"gameView" sender:self];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];*/
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

This is how my storyboard looks like
[image: storyboard]

Comment: What's the value, in `goToMainView` of `self.navigationController`?

Comment: Do you see `NSLog(@"I AM HERE");` printing and isn't `self.navigationController` `nil`?

Comment: Yes I do see "i am here" and self.navigationcontroller is nil @Azat

Comment: So it means that you not in `UINavigationController` stack

Comment: How do you show `PlayViewController`?

Comment: I have added my storyboard. View Controller(PlayViewController) is my parent controller for the subview. @azat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like one of the connections from `root view` to `view controller` in the attached screenshots is `modal` (or both?).
In this case the `view controller` is not part of navigation controller stack.

Try to change the types of these 2 segues to `push`.
This should add each of these view controllers to navigation controller's views stack and each of them will have a non-nil `navigationController` property.

Comment: They are all custom since i am using SWReveealViewController library for sidebar.

Comment: This is the reason why you can't pop to root of navigation controller. Because your view controller was never pushed to it.

Comment: Why do you have segues for these view controllers at all? Shouldn't you set them up in the code?

Comment: When you say set them up from code, do you mean load up using xib file?

Comment: I changed to push and it work. Is there anyway to hide nav bar in those views?

Comment: [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];